# Execute SQL query on Redshift using AWS fargate orchestrated by Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I could find many examples of invoking SQL script on Redshift using Lambda inside Step Function (ex: [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-etl-orchestration.html) works well), however I could not figured out how to execute SQL script using AWS Fargate in Step Functions. I could not figured out how to pass the Redshift credentials to execute the queries. In the lambda case it was easy as below. How to passing the credentials to Fargate Task probably is the same, however what are the commands to execute the SQL scripts?

```
"States": {
    "loadJob": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "loadJobETL",
      "Result": {
        "input": {
          "redshift_cluster_id": "<RS_CLUSTER>",
          "redshift_database": "<MY_DB>",
          "redshift_user": "<MY_DB>root",
          "redshift_schema": "MY_SCHEMA",
          "action": "load_customer_address",
          "sql_statement": [
            "begin transaction;",
            "MY_SQL_STATEMENT",
            "end transaction;"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "loadJobETL": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:function:SOME_FUNCTION",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 180,
      "HeartbeatSeconds": 60,
      "InputPath": "$",
      "ResultPath": "$",
      "Next": "checkStatus"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) [Optimized Integration with ECS RunTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html). Which might look like what's below. As to what the code will look like in your Fargate container, that would depend on your chosen language but I would expect to use the AWS SDK and look very similar to what you included in your Lambda code.

```
{
  "StartAt": "loadJob",
  "States": {
    "loadJob": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "loadJobETL",
      "Result": {
        "input": {
          "redshift_cluster_id": "<RS_CLUSTER>",
          "redshift_database": "<MY_DB>",
          "redshift_user": "<MY_DB>root",
          "redshift_schema": "MY_SCHEMA",
          "action": "load_customer_address",
          "sql_statement": [
            "begin transaction;",
            "MY_SQL_STATEMENT",
            "end transaction;"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "loadJobETL": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "Cluster": "arn:aws:ecs:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:cluster/MyECSCluster",
        "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:REGION:ACCOUNT_ID:task-definition/MyTaskDefinition:1",
        "Overrides": {
          "ContainerOverrides": [
            {
              "Name": "container-name",
              "Command.$": "$"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, depending on the size of the output, you may be able to just run this directly from Step Functions using `arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:redshiftdata:executeStatement`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, would redshift input param will automatically be recognized by ECS to execute the SQL? Do I need to write something in command.$ ? (I am new to SWE and AWS)

Comment: ECS will just run your container for you. You would write the code to take the command that's passed and use it to execute the SQL Statement. Given that's just a container, what it does with the command is completely up to what you have in that container. If you just want to run the query, I'd suggest you give my suggestion of using the Step Functions integration a try.

Comment: You need to map those input parameters to environment variables in the Container Overrides.

Comment: @JustinCallison could not find anywhere if redshiftdata:executeStatement has a timeout limit as lambda has. Can we run long queries more than 20 min via redshiftdata:executeStatement API call ?